# How do i add SSO intergration to my self managed gitlab instance?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, keycloak, omniauth, omniauth-saml

I  have successfully deployed a gitlab instance into my GCP cluster using the `helm` installation as shown below.

```
upgrade_install_line="gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
  --timeout 600s \
  --namespace ${helm_namespace} \
  --set global.hosts.domain=${hosts_domain} \
  --set global.hosts.externalIP=${static_ip} \
....
etc
```

I would like to add Single Sign On to this instance using keycloak, Is there a way to add keycloak authentication to this installation. I am also attempting to add omniauth like this `--set global.omniauth.enabled= true` but not sure if it'll work.

What is the best way to achieve this, using helm.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak is not directly supported by a specific integration, however, you can configure Keycloak with the [SAML omniauth integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/saml.html) using the [SAML IDP](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#saml-v2-0-identity-providers) capability in Keycloak.

Comment: its the SAML omniauth integration i'm looking at, but not sure how the configuration works with a helm installed gitlab in a k8s cluster

Comment: What about the configuration do you need help understanding? The linked GitLab doc describes all the configuration required. It shouldn't make a difference whether you deploy with k8s/helm. You just follow the omnibus instructions @eagercoder